Swift VPN Configuration with NEVPNProtocolIKEv2: How to Handle Identity Data from .mobileconfig?
I am trying to establish a connection using NetworkExtension and NEVPNProtocolIKEv2. It needs to work on an iOS device. I have a test.mobileconfig file and I have set up all configurations based on its content. However, I am unsure how to assign the value for identityData. I have tried multiple methods, but each time, I receive the following errors on my server:
"ikev2-cp"[200] "my_ip_address" #1387: Peer attempted EAP authentication, but IKE_AUTH is required
"ikev2-cp"[200] "my_ip_address" #1387: responding to IKE_AUTH message (ID 1) from "my_ip_address" with encrypted notification AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
"ikev2-cp"[200] "my_ip_address" #1387: encountered fatal error in state STATE_V2_PARENT_R1

First of all, I used the first PayloadContent value inside the .mobileconfig file that I tested. I should mention that there is a certificate inside the file. However, the certificate is not password-protected.
let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
let kcs = KeychainService()
p.certificateType = .RSA
p.authenticationMethod = .certificate

kcs.save(key: "ikev2_password", value: password as String)
p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "ikev2_password")

let base64String = """
MIIQ6AIBA....AggA
"""

if let certData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
    p.identityData = certData
    p.authenticationMethod = .certificate
    p.identityDataPassword = "cHH...B3"
} else {
    print("decode error")
}

Additionally, inside the file, I see: Does this indicate that I need to change something?
<key>PayloadType</key>
<string>com.apple.vpn.managed</string>
...
<key>PayloadType</key>
<string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>

Here is my full code for ikev2
func getIKEv2Protocol(address: NSString, username: NSString, password: NSString) -> NEVPNProtocolIPSec {
        
        let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
        let kcs = KeychainService()

        p.certificateType = .RSA
        p.authenticationMethod = .certificate
    
        kcs.save(key: "ikev2_password", value: password as String)
        p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "ikev2_password")
        p.identityDataPassword = "cHH....B3"
        
        p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256GCM
        p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
        p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group19
        p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1410

        p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256GCM
        p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
        p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group19
        p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1410

        if let certData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
            p.identityData = certData
            p.authenticationMethod = .certificate
        
        } 
        p.serverCertificateIssuerCommonName = "xxx"
        p.serverCertificateCommonName = "xxx-2"


        p.deadPeerDetectionRate = .medium
        p.disableRedirect = true
        p.enableRevocationCheck = false
        p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
        p.remoteIdentifier = address as String
        p.localIdentifier = username as String
        p.serverAddress = address as String

        p.enablePFS = false

     return p;
    }

and
let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
// inside > vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error) -> Void in
let p = self.getIKEv2Protocol(address: address, username: username, password: password)
vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = p
vpnManager.localizedDescription = "IKEv2 VPN"
vpnManager.isEnabled = true


vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
 ...
   vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { error in
    ...
    try vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel() 
    // And this section starts without any errors.

How can I properly provide the value for p.identityData and .mobileconfig password?
Please explain in detail if there is an answer, as I am inexperienced with Swift and VPNs.

base64String = mobileConfigFirstBase64Key

It seems you have an unusual setup: you're configuring IKEv2 with certificate authentication plus EAP. This is a valid setup but not very common. So first make sure you can establish the connection using a generic IKEv2 client, then mimic that configuration.
An identity in this specific context means a certificate plus associated private key. It's expected that these are stored in a PKCS#12 container, which is the data you assign to identityData. Since PKCS#12 containers are usually password protected, you need to assign the password needed to decrypt this container to identityDataPassword.
So validate that the data you feed to identityData:

… is in PKCS#12 format
… contains an RSA certificate (because of p.certificateType = .RSA)
… contains the private key
… and can be decrypted using the password you feed to identityDataPassword

(How to validate that is beyond the scope of this answer; sorry.)
if let certData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
    p.identityData = certData
    p.identityDataPassword = passwordToDecryptCertData
    p.authenticationMethod = .certificate       
} else {
    // No identity (cert+private key)? Since no PSK seems to be used
    // either, authentication must be .none and EAP must be used.
    p.authenticationMethod = .none
}

Note that simply assigning a public certificate without a private key won't work here. For IKEv2 certificate authentication, the private key of your certificate is needed.

Will there be any difference for the Certificate-based Authentication type in the mobileconfig? Because I'm not sure about this information.
I have my CA certificate within the mobileconfig, and it matches with this p12. @DarkDust

The CA certificate is not what you assign to identityData. As far as I know, you need to install it into your keychain and trust it (beyond the scope of this question), then you configure serverCertificateIssuerCommonName as you already do. Does the connection from your mobileconfig work correctly? If not, take a generic IKEv2 client and make sure you have the connection settings right first, then try to code it.

I'm not trying to set the CA certificate into identityData; instead, I'm trying to set the first key from the mobileconfig(base64String). When I tried this key with my password "cHH...B3", it was validate. So, it seems there's no issue with the password. The VPN created via mobileconfig works properly when accessed from the device settings. However, the one added through the code does not work.
Password cHH...B3
PayloadCertificateFileNamexxx-2
PayloadContent
MIIQ6AIBAzC... // this is base64String


Do you know of any additional resources I could benefit from on this topic? I have been struggling with this issue for days.


Since I don't have access to the precise mobileconfig file nor your precise code, all I can tell you is what I've outlined in my answer: identityData needs to be a PKCS#12 with just a certificate, private key, and needs to be decodable using the password you're passing to identityDataPassword. Verify this data, e.g. using openssl commands.

I am able to extract the file without providing a password (my .p12 file is not password-protected) using the command: openssl pkcs12 -in xxx_2.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out private_xxx_2.key . However, my issue here is the following: For IKEv2 on iOS, they recommend using .mobileconfig, as mentioned here: IKEv2 [https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/ikev2-howto.md#configure-ikev2-vpn-clients](Setup for iOS). Additionally, I do not have the .p12 file itself to provide to the identity data. If you know a way to provide it as a string, please share it with me.
